# Progress bar inside pdfmake

Tags: javascript, pdfmake

I'm trying to implement progress bar inside PDF using pdfmake js library.
Gone through working examples mentioned here [vectors in pdfmake](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/blob/master/examples/vectors.js), but unable to find progress or partial filled canvas example.

I'm looking for workaround which depicts rectangular canvas with filled color based on dynamic value like below.

```
  {
    canvas: [         
      {
        type: 'line',
        x1: 40, y1: 100,
        x2: 260, y2: 100,
        lineWidth: 10,
        lineCap: 'square',
        lineColor: 'green',
       // fillPercentage: 20
      }          
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found workaround.

solution_1:
 stacking 2 lines.

```
{
   canvas: [
    {
      type: 'line',
      x1: 10, y1: 100,
      x2: 100, y2: 100,
      lineWidth: 15,
      lineColor: '#eef2d7',
      lineCap: 'round'
    },
    {
      type: 'line',
      x1: 10, y1: 100,
      x2: 50, y2: 100, // 50 percent completion
      lineWidth: 15,
      lineColor: 'green',
      lineCap: 'round'
    }
  ]
}
```

solution_2:
 stacking 2 rectangular.

```
{
   canvas: [
    {
        type: 'rect',
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        w: 100,
        h: 30,
        opacity: 0.1,
        color: 'white',
        lineColor: 'black'
    },
    {
        type: 'rect',
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        w: 70, // 70 percent completion
        h: 30,
        color: 'green',
        lineColor: 'black'
    },
  ]
}
```